# What is the name for the psychological effect in which formulating a question answers that very question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, psychology

Like [this poster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20016/why-is-it-that-properly-formulating-your-question-for-stackoverflow-often-yield), I often find that when I'm stuck on a problem, the mere act of formulating a problem as a question to post on StackOverflow is sufficient to make me think about it in a new way, and consequently solve it on my own. I'm almost certain I've heard a name for this psychological effect before, but I can't seem to put my finger on it, and searching for it isn't bringing up any results I recognise. Does anyone have any leads on this?

Comment: @James: Haha...good, but not quite. You know...the "I just answered my own question by asking it" effect. I just thought I had heard another name for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean like *[cardboard programmer](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?CardboardProgrammer)* or *[rubber duck debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)*?

Comment: Ironically, the second article contains a reference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106683/what-is-this-particular-type-of-revelation-called, of which this question is a duplicate.

Comment: The rubber duck! I knew it had a fun anecdote to go with. @John: My apologies for lack of proper search procedures.

Comment: why link to mobile wikipedia?

Comment: @down because I'm on my iPod while holding the grumpy baby, feel free to edit the link or I will when I get the use of both hands again

Comment: I was just curious, I admire your ability to still answer while holding a baby @rich

Comment: Wait a second -- Wikipedia cites that SO question, but the accepted answer to that question merely links to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 5):

if only you were experiencing it now...

Comment: Just my luck, eh?